# jquery data table order

Tags: jquery, codeigniter, datatable

Hi guys I am not very well versed in jquery, well not at all actually.

I inherited this project where previous guy used jquery dataTable plugin.

He has this table that i just want to reverse order to desc.

I have no idea where does he even initialize the table other than giving it a class fullwidth datatable.

I have tried this and I get the right order but it also gives an error:

> DataTables warning: Cannot reinitialise DataTable.
>
> To retrieve the DataTables object for this table, please pass either
>   no arguments to the dataTable() function, or set bRetrieve to true.
>   Alternatively, to destory the old table and create a new one, set
>   bDestroy to true (note that a lot of changes to the configuration can
>   be made through the API which is usually much faster).

View

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).re

ady(function() {

    $('.fullwidth').dataTable( {

        "aaSorting": [[0, 'desc']]

    } );
} );
</script>
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="fullwidth datatable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
```

I guess it tries to initialite data table for the second time and that is the problem.

Does anyone know how to fix this.

Any help would be appriciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are indeed trying to initialize dataTable a second time. Whoever worked on this project previously most likely has a hook that runs when the page is ready that runs on all tables with the `datatable` class. Something like this:

```
$('.datatable').dataTable();
```

For your problem, you can do one of these:

1. Remove the datatable class from your table. If you do this your current code should work
2. Find the place where the previous developer is magically initializing all `datatable` classes. It would likely be one of the JavaScript files included in this page, but it could also be in the `<body>` of the page. If it *is* in the `<body>` then you're in luck, because you can see it when you use `View Source` in your browser. Otherwise, simply search your JavaScript files. I mention finding it because he might left a sorting hook as well

Comment: Thanks for the answer mate.I would like to focus on the first solution, because this table is used on the whole page, so I would only like to change this one, if possible.I tried to remove the class but then I don't get a formatted table then. I found the javascript file where he is initializing all datatable classes, but how come I can't find fullwidth datatable that he is calling? I searched through the whole app with sublime CTRL-SHIFT-F and no luck.

Comment: For the fullwidth, check the CSS on the page. Most likely there's a CSS declaration giving it 100% width